# New Line in textarea tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a textarea tag in which I am inserting text with new lines.
e:g like this :

```
abc
def
ghi
```

After Submitting the form,I am serializing all the form values including this textarea field.

the issues is that when I am trying to display this value (echo $textarea) ,it is giving the ouput without new lines. ie:

```
abc\r\ndef\r\nghi\r\n
```

Can anyone have any idea what is the issue here ??

here is my code.I am submiting my form with jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var form = $('form');
var submit = $('#submit');
form.on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();  
$.ajax({
  url: 'comment.php',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
   data: form.serialize(),     
  success: function(data){
    var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
    $('.section').prepend(item);  
  },
  error: function(e){
    alert(e);
  }
 });
 });
 });
</script>
```

here is the code through which I am trying to display the data

```
<div class="comment">
<div class="comment1">
<h3><?php echo $name ?> <span>said....</span></h3>
<p><?php echo nl2br($comment)?></p>
</div>
</div>
```

here's is how I am geting the $comment

```
<?php
if (isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] )):
include('./connection.php');
if (!empty($_POST['name']) AND !empty($_POST['textarea']) ) {
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textarea']); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the browser, you'd need `nl2br()` as all white-space - including new-lines - is reduced to a single space in the browser. It would show correctly as it is in your textarea though.

Comment: i tried with nl2br($textarea) but no luck

Comment: @user3318980 How are you serializing and de-serializing your strings? You should post `var_dump()`'s of the variable after every step.

Comment: @jeroen : sir you should wait for sometime before voting :(

Comment: You should post the complete `comment.php` as now we cannot see where your variable comes from. Also post a `var_dump($comment);`

Comment: Try this by `<pre><textarea>values</textarea></pre>` You might also want to do the same when inserting data into your rb (this way you don't need to use nl2br and in my experience this method is sometimes better)

Comment: @SuperDj : tried.but not working

Comment: @user3318980 I have edit my answer. BTW, You have not showed us how you get `$comment`. I assume you are using `$_POST` , is that correct? Please show us

Comment: You should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` only when you insert the data into the database and nowhere else. Although you really should switch to PDO or mysqli. When you output to html, you should use your original input and use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode it.

Comment: @jeron : yes I am inserting the data into mysql.tried with htmlspecialchars() also but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears OP is showing the `<textarea>` content again without using a `<textarea>` again. Using `nl2br()` was in the right direction.

The solution is to change:

```
echo $comment;
```

into:

```
echo str_replace(array("\t","  "),array("&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;"),nl2br(htmlspecialchars($comment)));
```

**edit**

I see you are using `mysql_real_escape_string();` when getting `$comment`. Remove `mysql_real_escape_string()` here, and put it only when you are going to use other `mysql_*` functions.

The `mysql_real_escape_string()` is messing up your new lines.

Comment: this is also not worked out. it removed the \ i:e abc\r\ndef\r\nghi\r\n converted into abcrndefrnghirn

Comment: ["\r\n" has nothing to do with magic quotes…](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: @nlx : thanks for the help mate..unfortunately the issue remains.I will try to do some rnd on my main on this.

Answer (score 0):

use the echo `nl2br($textarea)`. 
It adds a `br` tag at every point that there is newline (newline to break)